# How to store incoming UDP messages in database and make accessible via REST API?

Tags: python, sockets, flask, udp, twisted

I am working on a project whereby I have a couple of remote IoT devices that send messages via UDP. I am looking to make a server that can receive this constant flow of UDP messages and can store them in a database. Additionally I would like to make a (REST) API which allows the information from this database to be accessed (every 15/30 minutes or so) from other applications.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this (preferably in python)?

So far I **am** able to do the following (in python):

- I know how to make a UDP client and server, and send messages between them using "socket". [This link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrywtW7nn2w) provided a useful explanation.
- I know how to create a Flask server, store random data in a database using SQLAlchemy, and make the database content available via an API that can be accessed via Postman. [This link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=qbLc5a9jdXo) showed me how.

What I am **not** able to do:

- Tying everything together is where the problem arises. Specifically I don't know how to combine these above methods so that everything works at the same time (in the same loop so to say). Both Flask and the UDP server are running their own loops and listening (for events?) so I don't see how those processes would work simultaneously.

One thing that I was considering is to run the UDP server + database insertion in one terminal, and the Flask/API server from another terminal. That would mean that the database is being opened and accessed by multiple programs at the same time. Is that possible? It would be like opening a single Excel sheet multiple times (which is not permitted I would think).

I also came across [this library](https://github.com/heroku-python/flask-sockets) which allows you to combine Flask with Flask-Sockets, but that doesn't seem to support UDP as far as I understand..

Many thanks!

Comment: It depends on the database. Most databases and data stores are multi-user. SQLite is a notable exception. However SQLite works fine if you have only one writer process (your UDP server) and multiple reader processes (your REST API).